# how can i subscribe to message events in my slack app

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, bots, slack, slack-api

i will explain our slack app flow

We created a Slack app, and added several slash commands which calls my server.

My server have logic which performs some operations according to the route and sent response back which currently working fine.

But we are trying to improve this, by eliminating the slash commands. in otherwords we looking for a interface similar to chatgpt. for example, If i write 'Who is current US president?' i need that question text in my server. then i can utilise chatgpt or any other Langchain technologies to fetch information and pass to user

here the blocker is, how can i get the message text which entered by the user in my slack app.

Any helps is highly appreciated

Thank You